# Trebuchet launch into space

Tags: gravity

I was reading some questions on your site about using a Trebuchet to launch a payload into space.
Would it be possible to use the same sort of principle, but to have, say a 100 mile steel cable attached to the earth, or tower, on the other end have a rocket launching straight up, and use the rotation of the earth to help launch a craft into space. the cable would suffer at the fast end, but the space craft would only have to carry a fraction of the fuel needed at the moment. Is any of this possible?

Comment: Which questions?

Comment: This sounds like basically a means of velocity redirection. I can't clearly identify how it could be helpful, but I'm sure it could. Direct contact forces can reduce gravity drag in a wide variety of configurations, and that might be true here. But the problem is that tethers are no good for speeds much more than 2 km/s or so, and orbital speed is much higher. Materials aren't strong enough, so the taper ratio diverges to absurd numbers. You can't get around the taper mass absurdity with any adjustments to the configuration. The constraint is in the units.

Comment: for something similar, see the Wikipedia article on [space elevators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator)

Comment: The question is a bit of thinking big, which is good in itself, even if the actual construction is out of reach of present day materials. I would put it differently: Could you make a large trebuchet capable of throwing a fueled-up rocket at some initial velocity fast enough to fire the rocket while in mid-flight? This would get it off the ground, which would save a large amount of fuel at any velocity above zero.
It's really wasteful to launch rockets straight up from a zero velocity when you have to carry so much fuel to ultimately reach escape velocity. And, the weight of the fuel itself req